# Consulta SQL para arreglar acentos mal codificados

Tags: mysql, sql, codificación

Por un error, he introducido registros en una tabla con los acentos del tipo Ã³, Ã¡.

Normalmente guardamos los registros con los acentos correctos. Por lo que me gustaría saber si hay alguna consulta que pueda aplicarle a la tabla para que sustituya esos **Ã³** por su correspondiente letra con su acento.

Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tienes claro cuál es la correspondencia entre los que están mal y cómo deberían estar, puedes usar un replace (los caracteres que he puesto no tienen por qué ser los correctos):

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo = REPLACE(campo, 'Ã³', 'á');
```

Una cosa a tener en cuenta es que, según el motor de base de datos, existirá la función REPLACE o se llamará de otro modo

Comment: Dependiendo el número de registros que tenga en esa tabla añadiría un `WHERE campo LIKE('%Ã³%')` para evitar que intente hacer el replace sobre todos los registros de esa tabla

Comment: Con la ayuda de los dos lo he conseguido, gracias